# One-hot encoding with model.matrix. Is the intercept required?

Tags: r, r-caret

I understand what one-hot encoding does in converting a factor with k levels to k-1 dummy variables, but what I'm confused about is whether the intercept is required to be specified or can be left out. For example, this removes the intercept:

```
# Predictor variables of train dataset
x <- model.matrix(y ~ ., train_data)[,-1]
```

But the model output seems the same regardless of whether I remove it or not.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you can leave the intercept out like `model.matrix(~ a + 0, data=data.frame(a=factor(1:3)))` which will give you a slightly different result.

Comment: This might be better asked over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) since you're really just reparametrizing the model. A linear combination of the dummy variables would act as the new "intercept" (provided the rank of the model matrices are the same).

Comment: Some online examples I'd seen had removed the in intercept with [,-1], but then I thought I had read somewhere you should only do that if you retain as many dummies as there are levels of the factor. I just wasn't sure. I've posted over at Cross Validated.

Comment: The main idea is that you don't want your ``model.matrix`` to be singular. So it's either the intercept + k-1 dummies, or no intercept and all k dummies. It can be shown that the result should be the same, just with slight differences in parameter interpretation.